# Javascript function called by itself

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to display a customized alert when i click a  but if im logged in i want to redirect to another page. I have this.

```
        <div id="contentCalendar" class="col-md-3 images_1_of_4 text-center">
            <a><img onClick="show_alert();" id="rotateme" class="img-responsive img-circle center-block" src="web/images/calendaricon.png"/></a>
            <h4><a href="#">Check our last events</a></h4>

        </div>
        <div id="myalert" class="alert alert-error">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
        <strong>Error!</strong> You must be logged in to see our calendar.
        </div>  
        <script>    
        $('#myalert').hide(); 
        //What happen if you want to enter the events without loggin.
        var logged_in = <?php echo ($logged_in); ?>;
        function show_alert()
        {
            if(logged_in==true)
            {
                window.location="timeline.php";
            }
            else
            {
                $('#myalert').show();
            }
        }
        </script>
```

For some reason works like a charm when Logged_in is true and i get redirected. But when im logged out it just doesnt show the alert even if i didnt press the button at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try converting the value you set from PHP to a boolean value as it's probably being read as a string.

Comment: Most likely the value of logged_in is not true in your success case but some truthy value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always, again, *always*, run everything you embed in JS through `json_encode`:

```
var logged_in = <?php echo json_encode($logged_in); ?>;
```

When you simply `echo` a falsy value in php, it echoes nothing, thus breaking your javascript.

Comment: Hey, that's exactly the problem indeed. Now works great. I had no idea that not encoding it will break if i get a false value. So i guess i was just lucky to reach that far. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this line:

```
var logged_in = <?php echo $logged_in ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the php code outputs the Boolean correctly. Viewing the page source will allow you to see if it is outputted correctly.

Now looking at the JavaScript code.

Move the onclick to the anchor and cancel the click event

```
<a href="#" onclick="show_alert(); return false"><img ....
```

---

A better solution is to dump the inline event handler.

Attach the click unobtrusively and use preventDefault to cancel the click.

HTML:

```
<a href="timeline.php" class="calendar"><img ....
```

JavaScript

```
var logged_in = <?php echo ($logged_in); ?>;
$("a.calendar").on("click", function (e) { 
    if(!logged_in) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#myalert').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: dont suggest inline handlers at all

Comment: @Alex just fixing the OPs code the way they did it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap the script in some kind of event. Try :

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  var logged_in = <?php echo ($logged_in); ?>;
        function show_alert()
        {
            if(logged_in==true)
            {
                window.location="timeline.php";
            }
            else
            {
                $('#myalert').show();
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is necessary?

Comment: It looks to me like he has the script in the body tag or after it, be sure to put the script outside of the body tag either after or before (in the <head> </head>

Comment: function statements are being executed/defined at runtime, not when events trigger. they have the respective scropes, though